# How to show view controls in the new update of Xcode 12?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I have updated `xcode` to the latest version ( Version 12.0 (12A7209)) and I can't show 
the toggle icons that show/hide inspector, debug or navigator Area
How can I show them again?

[image]

Comment: For navigator the button is at far left.  For inspector the button is at far right. For debug area use Shift Command Y.

Comment: I am asking about the design itself, is no longer exist

Comment: Well yes. It’s a new design. So?

Comment: Yes they replace it with only one button that open/hide Inspector panel only

Comment: Yes except it’s two buttons, as I said. One on the left for the navigator, one on the right for the inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the navigator the button is now at the far left, or use Command 0.

For the inspector the button is now at the far right, or use Command Option 0.

[image]

Also, in full screen mode you can summon the inspectors as overlays by hovering at the side with the mouse. Very cool as it saves space.

For the debug area there is no button; use Shift Command Y.

Basically this is a good time to learn the keyboard shortcuts!

Comment: For the debug area there is a button, only if the debug area is open :)

Comment: This change is absolutely ridiculous.